# Gdb set binary value on register

Tags: variables, binary, gdb

Inside gdb I am trying to set a binary value on a register.

```
(gdb) set $a=10010
(gdb) p /t $a
$1 = 10011100011010
```

Is there any way to set a binary value to a register in GDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `0b` numeric prefix, or if you'll be entering base-2 numbers a lot, try the [set input-radix](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Numbers.html#index-set-input_002dradix) command:

```
(gdb) set $a=0b10010
(gdb) print $a
$1 = 18
(gdb) print /t $a
$2 = 10010
(gdb) set input-radix 2
Input radix now set to decimal 2, hex 2, octal 2.
(gdb) print 10010
$3 = 18
....
(gdb) set input-radix 0t10
Input radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.
```